# Does ChatJS support Facebook style friends list?

Tags: signalr, chatjs

I want to use [ChatJS](http://www.chatjs.net) in much the same way facebook does. The way I anticipate achieving this is to have one chatroom with everyone added to it. The users contact list will be filtered by those in their network.

Is there any issue with doing it like this? What would be the best way to achieve it if I'm wrong? Does this method scale well?

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook style rooms are being developed now. It's on June 15th. This functionality is going to be implemented this way:

- If the developer chooses to use a fixed room, the users in the room will be presented exactly the way Facebook displays your friends. You will not need to choose the rooms, and the default room will enter automatically.
- It's not going to be possible to broadcast messages to the entire room.

I'll update this answer as it gets finished.

Answer (score -1):

I think It can not create any problem for small modules but can create problem when a large number of users

Comment: Can you provide some factual support for this primarily opinion-based answer?